# Typescript error when returning Response and accessing member

Tags: javascript, typescript

This code works fine:

```
const { response } = yield call(makeGetRequest, requestUrl);
return response.data;
```

However, this does not:

```
function makeCall() {
  ...
  const { response } = yield call(makeGetRequest, requestUrl);
  return response;
}

function returnData() {
  const response = makeCall();
  return response.data;
}
```

The typescript error is in the return response.data line:
Property data does not exist on type.

I assume this is because it is treating response as an any, but I have no idea how I would give the method the right info about what type of object response is. I tried typeof response and just got Object.

Comment: Well you'll definitely want to look into what types the function is returning, but a quick and dirty fix may be to just cast response as any. ```return response as any.data```  Also, if the data being returned from the request is always of a uniform type, I would take advantage of TS to define my own type for it if one doesn't exist in a library.

Answer (score 1):

is makeCall meant to be a generator function? It has to be if you're using  using `yield`, so presumably you meant to type `function* makeCall()`. But if it's a generator, then when you do this:

```
function returnData() {
  const response = makeCall();
  return response.data;
}
```

... the return value of makeCall() is an iterator object. Iterators have no .data property, which is why typescript is giving you an error.

As for how to correct this, i'll need more information about what you're trying to do. Is this redux-saga code? If so, you shouldn't be calling sagas yourself, but instead you have it listen to actions (eg, with [take, takeEvery, or takeLatest](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#takechannel)) and redux saga will run the saga when the actions occur.

If you want to call a saga from another saga you can, but you'll either need to use yield*:

```
function otherSaga*() {
  const response = yield* makeCall()
  console.log(response.data);
}
```

Or the call effect:

```
function otherSaga*() {
  const response = yield call(makeCall);
  console.log(response.data);
}
```